# Wampserver2.2 suddenly stopped working

Tags: server, wampserver

I have been using wampserver2.2 for several months, and today it just stopped working. Yesterday It was working, and today not. I didn't install any programs and didn't touch any files of Wampserver2.2.
Normally I am developing a drupal site on my localhost. Now I cannot connect to localhost. So:

- the menu icon on the bottom-right stays red no matter how much I restart.
- When I right click and click : "Put Online", it says : "Could not execute menu item (internal error) [Exception] Could not perform service action: The service has not started"
- I am not running skype or any other program that would use port:80. In fact, when I click on the Wamp server icon -> Apache -> Service -> Test Port 80 it says: "Your port 80 is not actually used."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work. First, I restarted the PC and then did the following:

- pressed Win + R (or go to start -> run)
- then write "services.msc" and open it
- find wampapache -> right click and start (or restart)
- find wampmysqld -> ight click and start (or restart)

this forced the services to start, despite the fact that trying to start them from the wampserver menu icon on the bottor right had no effect.

Comment: Starting services sometimes also start dependencies (i.e., other services upon which this service rely). If you want to avoid this, make sure you selected "Automatic" instead of "Manual" or "Disabled" for those services and any dependencies.